# how to retrieve an image src attribute from a popup to the parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I call a js function from the popup like this:

```
<img onclick=parent.updateFunction('"+ item.id +"','"+ item.image +"','"+ item.label +"'); src=/mypath/ />
```

this is how I try to display the src attribute in hte parent page:

```
  function updateFunction(id, image, label) {

  alert($(this).attr('src'));
```

The result is undefined for now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `this.src` to the function. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/vPyMm/)

```
<img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" onclick ="update(this.src)" />

//script
update = function(src){
 alert(src);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest don't use inline JavaScript

```
<img src="test.jpg" />
```

use this to get the `src`

```
$('img').click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: thx but I don't know I can't use jquery in this popup all my tries where ineffective..